# Alamofire getting response body separately

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am unable to separate Response Body from response.
Alamofire request-

```
AF.request(www.example.com, method: .post, parameters: parameters).response{
response in
debugPrint(response)
self.label_1.text - "Response Body:\(response)"
}
```

response-

```
[Response]: 

[Status Code]: 200

[Headers]:

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 51

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 01:23:39 GMT

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=500

Server: Apache/2.2

Vary: Accept-Encoding

Via: 1.1 alproxy

[Response Body]: 

New record created successfully

[Data]: 31 bytes

[Network Duration]: 0.4341869354248047s

[Serialization Duration]: 0.0s

[Result]: success(Optional(31 bytes))
```

how do I fetch "New record created successfully" from the response?
Also in my database service, some times the response will be an array of objects (here it's a string), if I want to fetch an array will the code be different than fetching a string (as in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation for the [`DataResponse` type](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Structs/DataResponse.html#/s:9Alamofire12DataResponseV5valuexSgvp), you'll see that you can access the components of the `response` by accessing its properties. In your case, you'd want to access the `value` property, which is a `Data?` by default. If you expect to parse `String` values, you'd want to use the `responseString` handler, rather than just `response`, so you get the `String` created for you automatically.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your response. I checked the link you provided.
if I do debugPrint(response.value) -> I get -> Optional(Optional(31 bytes))
if I do debugPrint(response.data) -> I get -> Optional(31 bytes)
I also tried "Response Body:\(response)" -> I get -> success(Optional(31bytes))
Still not sure how I can get  "New record created successfully". could you please help with code snippet maybe?

Comment: Yes, you're seeing that because you're not actually decoding the `Data` into a `String`, the `debugPrint` is doing it. You need to use `responseString` like I suggested, or turn the `Data` into a `String` yourself.

Comment: Thanks.
AF.request(www.example.com, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString{ response in debugPrint(response) self.label_1.text = "\(response)" } 
this worked to give me-> success("New record creaed successfully") in the label and same is printed in console(debugPrint) under Result.
any quick way to get rid of that success? I'm just trying cutting the string now. but would be great if I could get it just as- New record creaed successfully

Comment: Yes, like I said, unwrap `response.value` to access the successfully parsed `String`.